# composer update returns requirements could not be resolved

Tags: composer-php

```
$ composer update 
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)           
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.3.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.3.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.3.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.2.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.1.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.1.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.1.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.5 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.4 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.2.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.3.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.3 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.3.0, v3.3.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Why is it so difficult to just read the given message?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the mongodb extension is not installed our outdated.

Check the documentation to install mongodb for your operating system: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setup.php

and make sure the extension is enabled in your php.ini by checking for:

```
extension=mongodb.so
```

If the system you are using is different from where the code will run and that is why you don't have the extension installed you can also choose to [ignore the platform requirements](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update).